# Node version incompatible when installing Strapi Starter Next Ecommerce

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, strapi

I'm new to node and I think the error is saying my node is too new. Other answers on this site are telling how to upgrade their node but how do I match my node with the one the package wants?

```
C:\react>npx create-strapi-starter@3 strapi-ecomm next-ecommerce
Need to install the following packages:
  create-strapi-starter@3
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'create-strapi-starter@3.6.8',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10.16.0 <=14.x.x', npm: '>=6.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.1', npm: '8.1.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'strapi-generate-new@3.6.8',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10.16.0 <=14.x.x', npm: '>=6.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.1', npm: '8.1.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
? Choose your installation type Quickstart (recommended)
Creating a quickstart project.
Creating a new Strapi application at C:\react\strapi-ecomm\backend.
Creating files.
Installing strapi/strapi-template-ecommerce template.
Error while installing dependencies:
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
error backend@0.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x". Got "16.13.1"
error Found incompatible module.

 Keep trying!

Oh, it seems that you encountered errors while installing dependencies in your project.
Don't give up, your project was created correctly.
Fix the issues mentioned in the installation errors and try to run the following command:

cd C:\react\strapi-ecomm\backend && yarn install

C:\react>cd C:\react\strapi-ecomm\backend

C:\react\strapi-ecomm\backend>yarn install
yarn install v1.22.17
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
info No lockfile found.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
error backend@0.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x". Got "16.13.1"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1 (NVM):

You have node `v16.13.1` (on Windows), the framework ideally needs Node 14.X.X, you will need to downgrade your node, or my recommendation is using something like NVM, instructions can be found on:

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#install-nvm-windows

Once installed you can run the following commands:

`nvm install v14.18.3`

and then `nvm use v14.18.3` and finally running your command and therefore resetting up your project: `npx create-strapi-starter@3 strapi-ecomm next-ecommerce`.

If you would like you can also create an `.nvmrc` file and add the version (`v14.18.3`) to it and default to it automatically in the desired directory.

For additional context, using NVM will allow you to use multiple verisons of NodeJS on your machine.

---

Option #2:

Uninstalling Node v16 and installing Node v14 from: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.18.3/

Comment: Thanks so much. I just installed nvm and I got this error ```npm WARN deprecated nvm@0.0.4: This is NOT the correct nvm. Visit https://nvm.sh and use the curl command to install it.``` I went to the doc and there's no instruction on how to ```curl``` it in Win10. Only Linux mentioned. Ok, I'll try your link.

Comment: @ratib90486 have you tried installing NVM from https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#install-nvm-windows and you should be able to ignore the error and still proceed with the rest of the commands provided in my answer

Comment: I followed your link and now my CLI says ```C:\>nvm install v14.18.3
This is not the package you are looking for: please go to http://nvm.sh```

Comment: Can you run `node -v` and see if the node version has been changed? It should ideally say `v14.18.3` and also please make sure you have reloaded your terminal after NVM installation.

Comment: ```C:\>nvm -v
This is not the package you are looking for: please go to http://nvm.sh``` hmmm this is quite odd. And yes I reloaded

Comment: Not `nvm -v` its `node -v` we need to check the node version

Comment: sorry it's still v16.13.1

Comment: Would removing your node version and reinstalling to NodeJS v14 be an option for you? If so the installer files are available on: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.18.3/

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks a lot!